# How to handle limitation of Robot Class in Selenium for Uploading Folders/Files?

Tags: upload, selenide

I have a scenario to Upload Folder in my app, which is currently automated using Robot Class in Selenium. 
The challenge I am facing is while running the code on Remote system, my code fails coz, multiple other programs are also executing in parallel and Keyboard mouse movement are only performed on active window by Robot class.

Need Suggestion to fix this limitation or any other alternative to handle Upload function in selenide which is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are you using Robot Class than you click on WebElement and after that appear os-window when you select you file.

If my assumption right then you must switch to selenium way of uploading files.

Find input with type='file' something like that `<input id='inputID' type='file'>` and just `.sendKeys("file location")`

---

`driver.findElement(By.id("inputID")).sendKeys("path/to/your/file");`

---